# Streambuilder snapshot.hasData always false

Tags: flutter, firebase

No error message is shown but the snapshot.hasData is always false, causing nothing to be shown on screen except for the circular progress indicator. None of the data is showing up.

```
child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
            .collection("Coins")
            .snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting;
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
            return Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text("Coin Name: ${document.id}"),
                  Text("Amount owned: ${document.data()['Amount']}"),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList());
        },
      ),
```

I tried changing it to this.

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting;
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
```

but a long list of error message popped up. Here is a snippet of it.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot>#622e8):
Unexpected null value.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
StreamBuilder
StreamBuilder:file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/flutter%20tutorial/authentication_page/lib/ui/home_page.dart:  24:18

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet

Comment: NEVER build  your stream in the stream: parameter of your StreamBuilder.  Watch this for details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg